# How to create a unique constraints in YML in Doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I Want to create a unique constraints on two attributs. The YML configuration with Doctrine2 isn't well documented. So I try to traduct the XML in YML. What's wrong with this code?

```
unique-constraints:
    name: event_user
    columns:
        event_id: ~
        user_id: ~
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally I managed to create it by this code:

```
    uniqueConstraints:
        event_user_idx:
            columns: event_id,user_id
```

But Thank Reuven for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is extremly hard to find good documentation for Doctrine-2 with Symfony-2.

Just small details for those who won't understand why this one does't work - you miss one tab before `event_user_idx` and another before `columns`. Yaml is sensitive to spaces...

Comment: Which level of the YAML file does the uniqueContraints section go?

Comment: @guyaloni: this is documented here : https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html?highlight=uniqueConstraints#unique-constraints

Answer (score 8):

You should try that:

```
uniqueConstraints:
  event_user:
    columns:
      - event_id
      - user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if [this part of the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/stable/reference/yaml-mapping.html#unique-constraints) has been added recently or not, but here is what it says:

```
# ECommerceProduct.orm.yml
ECommerceProduct:
  type: entity
  fields:
    # definition of some fields
  uniqueConstraints:
    search_idx:
      columns: [ name, email ]
```